# Creating a table of counts by some factor level in R

Tags: r

I have some data of foods eaten on different days.

```
day <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
food <- c('pizza','pizza','taco','snake','snake','taco','taco','pizza','taco','pizza','taco','snake')
all <- data.frame(day, food)
```

I'd like to create a table with food on the x axis, day on the y axis, and the number of foods per day in the matrices such that

```
food.list <- unique(all$food)
 day.list <- unique(all$day )
output <- data.frame(c(2,1,1),c(0,2,1),c(2,2,1))
output
      1 2 3
pizza 2 0 2
taco  1 2 2
snake 1 1 1
```

What is a straightforward way to solve this problem?

Comment: `?table`    .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data = all, formula = food~day, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "food")
   food 1 2 3
1 pizza 2 0 2
2 snake 1 1 1
3  taco 1 2 2
```

OR

```
table(all$food, all$day)

        1 2 3
  pizza 2 0 2
  snake 1 1 1
  taco  1 2 2
```

Comment: no need to transpose, just pass the variables in reverse order, either name them or `table(all[2:1])`

Answer (score 2):

It would be "tidier" to leave day, food and count in different columns. **Note**: I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the data frame, it avoids issues later.

```
library(dplyr)
all %>%
  group_by(day, food) %>% 
  tally()
```

But you can always `spread` if you really want days as columns:

```
library(tidyr)
all %>% 
  group_by(day, food) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  spread(day, n)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    food   `1`   `2`   `3`
* <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1  pizza     2    NA     2
2  snake     1     1     1
3   taco     1     2     2
```

and if you want NA to be 0, add:

```
%>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer, funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

Comment: `count` does `group_by(...) %>% tally()` in one go: `all %>% count(day, food)`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but what's wrong with `table`?

```
day = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
food = c('pizza','pizza','taco','snake','snake','taco','taco','pizza','taco','pizza','taco','snake')
table(food, day)

      day
food    1 2 3
  pizza 2 0 2
  snake 1 1 1
  taco  1 2 2
```

Comment: yup, *the* answer really is `table` . d.b. does give a table solution, but lower in precedence so +1

Comment: That's why I didn't saw it I guess.

Comment: jusr re-read my comment... it wasnt meant to suggest that you shouldnt of answered as it had already been given.. it was meant to say that table is the answer  ie just like this answer

Comment: Of course, I know that =)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(col~food+day, cbind(all, col=1))

# OR

xtabs(col~food+day, transform(all, col=1))

# OR

xtabs(~food+day, all) # thanks to user20650

#      day
#food    1 2 3
#  pizza 2 0 2
#  snake 1 1 1
#  taco  1 2 2
```